# Highlight text by link in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, highlight

I resently found out that in chrome you can highlight text in the link. This can be done by adding `#:~:text=` to the link. Example: [This](https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html) link does not highlight anything while [This](https://www.lipsum.com/feed/html#:~:text=Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet,%20consectetur%20adipiscing%20elit.) link highlights my chosen context. Since I discoverd this I'm using it all the time for showing somthing to a colleague.

My question is what is the browser suport for this? And if I try to highlight a whole paragraph it doesn't work, so what is the limmit?

I searched for a while without anny sucess.

---

**Edit**

After long trying i found that there is not a spesivic limit to this. It stops at a dot F.E. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#:~:text=Google%20Chrome%20is%20a%20cross-platform%20web%20browser%20developed%20by%20Google) is will work. and if i go farther like [This](http://Google%20Chrome%20is%20a%20cross-platform%20web%20browser%20developed%20by%20Google.%20It%20was%20first%20released%20in%202008%20for%20Microsoft%20Windows,%20and%20was%20later%20ported%20to%20Linux,%20macOS,%20iOS,%20and%20Android.%20The%20browser%20is%20also%20the%20main%20component%20of%20Chrome%20OS,%20where%20it%20serves%20as%20the%20platform%20for%20web%20apps.) won't bequse the text im searching goes trough after the first dot!

---

**Edit 2**

Having another look at the documentation I saw that you can add a begin and end preifelx. When useed you can select a whole paragraph like [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat#:~:text=The%20cat%20(Felis%20catus),%20About%2060%20cat%20breeds).

Answer (score 4):

[For ongoing detailed browser support information: [Scroll-To-Text Fragment support on **Can I use**](https://caniuse.com/url-scroll-to-text-fragment)]

Well, after some obscure googling I got [this](https://news.softpedia.com/news/how-to-use-google-chrome-to-link-to-text-on-page-524994.shtml)

TL;DR - it's a very interesting chrome-specific feature `Scroll To Text Fragment`. As mentioned [here](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096) there is no support in other browsers, albeit IE/Edge is in "public support" state (as they say, it used to be in IE5). Documentation is [here](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment/blob/master/README.md), and I don't see any size limits. Maybe the problem is in line break/begin-end paragraph special symbols handling?

UPD: other idea: there was a limit on GET-request length - 2,048 characters. Now it should be bigger, but maybe chrome still somehow cut/doesn't process too long URLs?

UPD2: The first guess is right. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)#:%7E:text=An%20artifact%20in%20the%20Unified%20Modeling%20Language%20(UML)%20is%20the%20specification%20of%20a%20physical%20piece%20of%20information%20that%20is%20used%20or%20produced%20by%20a%20software%20development%20process%2C%20or%20by%20deployment%20and%20operation%20of%20a%20system.%22%5B1%5D) link to wikipedia works, albeit [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)#:%7E:text=An%20artifact%20in%20the%20Unified%20Modeling%20Language%20(UML)%20is%20the%20specification%20of%20a%20physical%20piece%20of%20information%20that%20is%20used%20or%20produced%20by%20a%20software%20development%20process%2C%20or%20by%20deployment%20and%20operation%20of%20a%20system.%22%5B1%5D%0A), only one character more, doesn't. The problem is in 0A/0D "carrage return/line feed" characters: if they are present in text, even encoded, highlight won't work [at all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)#:%7E:text=system.%22%5B1%5D%0A). Possibly it's a bug and should be reported to Chrome, but still. Good thing for checking this is to paste selected text in Chrome "Search" tool: if it doesn't find pasted text and you see some strange characters - whoopsie.

Comment: If I take a look a the 'loprem ipsum' page and take the first paragrph and inspect it, it's only a paragraph no other HTml `attr`s. If i take the text to a char counter its 871 chars. Far under the GET limit

Comment: Speaking about https://www.lipsum.com/: I noticed that it auto-regenerates all text after first sentence, so it's a bad example. If we use something more persistent, like Wikipedia, the problem remains tho: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artifact_(UML)#:~:text=An%20artifact%20in%20the%20Unified%20Modeling%20Language%20(UML)%20is%20the%20specification%20of%20a%20physical%20piece%20of%20information%20that%20is%20used%20or%20produced%20by%20a%20software%20development%20process,%20or%20by%20deployment%20and%20operation%20of%20a%20system.%22[1]%20Examples